# How to work @DocumentReference in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reference, lazy-loading, one-to-many, spring-data-mongodb

I have two entities: Publisher and Book. Each one in specific collection in MongoDB.

```
@Document(collection = "publishers")
data class Publisher(
  @MongoId(value = FieldType.OBJECT_ID) 
  val id: ObjectId? = null,
  @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
  val books: MutableList<Book>,
  val name: String? = null,
  val arconym: String? = null,
  val foundationYear: Int? = null
)


@Document(collection = "books")
data class Book(
  @MongoId(value = FieldType.OBJECT_ID) val id: ObjectId? = null,
  val isbn13: String? = null,
  val title: String? = null,
  val pages : Int? = null,
)
```

I want to find all publishers in collection of publishers, that contains books with title "Title1"
I am running this request but get empty list:

```
@GetMapping("/find")
fun findPublishers(): MutableList<Publisher> {
    return mongoTemplate.find(
        Query().addCriteria(
            Criteria.where("books").elemMatch(
                Criteria.where("title").`is`("Title1")
            )
        ), Publisher::class.java
    )
}
```

I fount that it because of (lazy = true) in @DocumentReference. So if I do not use "lazy = true", MongoDB save all fields of books in collection of publishers, and my request work correctly.

I want to save in collection of publishers just ID of books like this and expect my request to work.

[I want to save results in MongoDB like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3kyc.png)

Help me please, if it is possible to do? I have founded information here https://spring.io/blog/2021/11/29/spring-data-mongodb-relation-modelling

So I want to add that request "mongoTemplate.findAll(Publisher::class.java)" work correctly in anyway.

Comment: I changed class Publisher in field "books" - now I save just ID of books, but not entities. So, I changed my request. It work as I need, but now it is two requests combined into one. So I want to save List of entities books and the problem still persists for me.

Comment: return mongoTemplate.find(
            Query().addCriteria(
                Criteria.where("books").`in`(
                    mongoTemplate.findOne(
                        Query.query(Criteria.where("title").`is`(title)),
                        Book::class.java
                    )?.id
                )
            ), Publisher::class.java
        )

Comment: So I still have not found solution of request db.getCollection("publishers").find({"books": {"$elemMatch": {"title": "Title1"}}}) to work without saving all fields of books in collection of publishers

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the solution using Spring Data MongoDB, but it is really easy to solve using MongoJack:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongojack/mongojack -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongojack</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongojack</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Create entities with links DBRef:

   ```
      @MongoCollection(name = "publishers")
      data class Publisher(
      @MongoId(value = FieldType.OBJECT_ID) 
      val id: ObjectId? = null,
      @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
      val books: MutableList<DBRef<Book, ObjectId>>,
      val name: String? = null,
      val arconym: String? = null,
      val foundationYear: Int? = null
      )
   ```

2. Find a publisher by Id

   `val publisher: Publisher = collectionOfPublishers.findOne(Filters.eq("_id", ObjectId("62acbc0f51df607f29896c3c")))`
3. Find books of the publisher:

.

```
   val dbReferenceManager: DbReferenceManager = DbReferenceManager(
   mongoClient, "publishers", UuidRepresentation.STANDARD
   )
    
   val booksOfPublisher = dbReferenceManager.fetch(book.articles)
```

It works in other way: we can find publisher by book if it necessary

For more information: https://mongojack.org/dbrefs.html